# Duplicate shape and change text in word using VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying to create a code that duplicates shape from a specific shape and changes the name of the shape to facilitate the manipulation - what I want to change is the text located in that shape. I tried but I didn't succeed.

This is my code:

```
If frame.Value = "2" Then
wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 643").Duplicate
wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 643").Name = " Groupe 644"

 Set shp = wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 643")

With shp
    .Left = Sheets("Feuil1").Range("J3")
End With
wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 644").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "FME1"
```

The problem that an error keeps saying:

> the element is not found

Comment: `.Name = " Groupe 644" you have an extra space in the beginning of the name, remove it.`

Comment: I didn't see that  , I'm gonna try it again

Comment: Now error 5917 : for  'wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 644").TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "FME1"' ..... this object can't Take in charge Txt

Comment: Well it seems that your shape is actually a Group, not an individual shape, isn't it?

Comment: Yes my shape is groupe not individual  ( there  is  a  Text Box 644 and autoline) the TextBox contain the word that I want to change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error message said, a group does not support a text frame. To access and set the `Textbox` inside the freshly created/copied group, you need to access it via the `GroupItems` property of the group shape.

You can access the group items either by index or by name. Try either of the following:

```
wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 643").GroupItems("Text Box 644").TextFrame.TextRange.text = "FME1"
```

or

```
wrdDoc.Shapes("Groupe 643").GroupItems("1").TextFrame.TextRange.text = "FME1"
```